# Product grid for a online catalog

Tags: html, html5

I have this portion of code and I would like to know if I did it right, what changes could be done to optimize and make it better, and if I used the all the tags the right way.  For the moment, the CSS part is not really done since I have few bugs on the height of each column.

```
<div class="shop-grid">
  <div class="container">
     <section class="col-group">
       <article class="col-3">
      <div class="item-container">
        <figure>
          <div class="container-thumb-screen"><span class="thumb-screen"></span></div>
            <img src="../public/uploads/productPictures/thumbnails/" alt="">
              <figcaption class="product-name">
                <h2><a href="">Hartie Copiator A4 Artist </a></h2>
              </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <div class="item-actions">
            <a href="" class="button"><i class="icon-heart"></i></a>
            <a href="" class="button"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
            <a href="" class="button"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      </article>
                    <article class="col-3">
      <div class="item-container">
        <figure>
          <div class="container-thumb-screen"><span class="thumb-screen"></span></div>
            <img src="../public/uploads/productPictures/thumbnails/" alt="">
              <figcaption class="product-name">
                <h2><a href="">Hartie Copiator A4 Xerox Bussines</a></h2>
              </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <div class="item-actions">
            <a href="" class="button"><i class="icon-heart"></i></a>
            <a href="" class="button"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
            <a href="" class="button"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      </article>
                    <article class="col-3">
      <div class="item-container">
        <figure>
          <div class="container-thumb-screen"><span class="thumb-screen"></span></div>
            <img src="../public/uploads/productPictures/thumbnails/" alt="">
              <figcaption class="product-name">
                <h2><a href="">Hartie Copiator A3 Xerox Bussines</a></h2>
              </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <div class="item-actions">
            <a href="" class="button"><i class="icon-heart"></i></a>
            <a href="" class="button"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
            <a href="" class="button"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      </article>
                    <article class="col-3">
      <div class="item-container">
        <figure>
          <div class="container-thumb-screen"><span class="thumb-screen"></span></div>
            <img src="../public/uploads/productPictures/thumbnails/" alt="">
              <figcaption class="product-name">
                <h2><a href="">Hartie Copiator A3 Maestro</a></h2>
              </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <div class="item-actions">
            <a href="" class="button"><i class="icon-heart"></i></a>
            <a href="" class="button"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
            <a href="" class="button"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      </article>
            </section>
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Having empty `alt`s is a code smell.

Comment: well i have an empty alt because i posted the html version didn't include the template vars that will populate with data in places where is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don’t use `i` for font icons. Use `span` instead (like you did with `.thumb-screen`). The [`i` element is not appropriate](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/41124/16414) for such purposes.

In any case, you should offer alternative content for user-agents that have no CSS support. I.e., your links in `.item-actions` couldn’t be accessed by, for example, screen reader users. So add content and optionally hide it visually.

Then you might also consider using an `ul` for the three link actions.

The `alt` attribute for `img` should have content, unless the image is only decorative (but then you should better use CSS instead).

No need for `h2` in `figcaption`. It’s already defined to be the caption (or "title" if you will) for this `figure`. It also doesn’t play a role in the document outline, because `figure` is a sectioning root. So if you want to provide a heading for the `article`, you need to place it outside of `figure`.

Comment: i will do the changes and come back with a new version :-)